# Module npm require a connection to database

Tags: javascript, node.js

I create an npm module.My module require a database connection from another npm module, for my first version when i require database module i passed static database configuration.

Is someone has the best idea how to pass database configuration dynamically.
Here an example of my code:

```
const db = require('database').database(
    {
        host: 'xxx',
        user: 'xxxx',
        password: 'xxx',
        database: 'xxx',
        ssl: true
    }
);
```

Comment: have you tried mysql npm package?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your module but, you could use environment variables into your modules to configure multiples environment and make your modules read a .env files with specific name of variables that you should write in a documentation

Comment: I know .env files but i am looking for better idea.thank u

Comment: are you using container based development or normal ?  I've kept in docker base file all connection related configuration. For normal case any config module or env are best available options

Comment: I use it normal.yes i think i will did it with a config  module or env.